# Convert XML to Json (Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content)

Tags: php, json, xml-parsing

I have a XML that I would want to convert to JSON.

XML is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:COMMAND xmlns:ns0="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/pinless/PINLESS.core/C2STransferBillPayment/Schema.xsd9">
   <ns0:TYPE>EXRCTRFRESP</ns0:TYPE>
   <ns0:TXNSTATUS>7893</ns0:TXNSTATUS>
   <ns0:DATE>14/02/18 12:22:30</ns0:DATE>
   <ns0:EXTREFNUM>Dibon20180214122227pnqeP1yxqN</ns0:EXTREFNUM>
   <ns0:TXNID />
   <ns0:MESSAGE>No such user exists, password is invalid.</ns0:MESSAGE>
</ns0:COMMAND>
```

I have tried

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$json = json_encode($xml);
```

But got `simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content`.

Anyone advice on how to convert the XML to JSON?

Comment: Are you sure that the XML document is UTF-8? Your XML is having UTF-8 in line 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a namespace issue 
try

```
$responsexml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$child_data_response = $responsexml->children('http://www.tibco.com/schemas/pinless/PINLESS.core/C2STransferBillPayment/Schema.xsd9');
print_r($child_data_response);
```

from there you can make it an object you can json encode or do whatever you want with it